# What is the behavior of the plus plus (++) operator when applied to a struct?

Tags: c, struct, arduino

I'm trying to learn C by playing with an Arduino Uno.  I'm reviewing the [code for the Colorduino library on github](https://github.com/lincomatic/Colorduino).  I'm wondering how `++` works when applied to a struct.

There is a `PixelRGB` struct defined in [Colorduino.h](https://github.com/lincomatic/Colorduino/blob/master/libraries/Colorduino/Colorduino.h):

```
typedef struct pixelRGB {
  unsigned char r;
  unsigned char g;
  unsigned char b;
} PixelRGB;
```

In [Colorduino.cpp](https://github.com/lincomatic/Colorduino/blob/master/libraries/Colorduino/Colorduino.cpp) there is a bit of code that applies the `++` operator to a `PixelRGB` pointer.  How does this work?

```
for (unsigned char y=0;y<ColorduinoScreenWidth;y++) {
  for(unsigned char x=0;x<ColorduinoScreenHeight;x++) {
    p->r = R;
    p->g = G;
    p->b = B;
    p++;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't really know c or arduino so I won't post this as an answer, but perhaps it increments all public fields?

Comment: In this case, you are incrementing a pointer to a structure that is p so now p will point to the next PixelRGB

Comment: Isn't this just pointer arithmetic?

Comment: @nhahtdh... probably, something I need to look up and read about again.

Comment: @Tanmoy, I think you are probably right

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note, that this code increments **pointer** to `PixelRGB`, not the struct itself.
So, the result of `++` when applied to pointer, is just incrementing its value by `sizeof(PixelRGB)`

Answer (score 5):

`p` is a pointer, not a struct, so it works like pointer arithmetic does on any type.  The pointer's value is an address.  So when, for example, you add `n` to a pointer, it's value changes and points to a new address `n * sizeof type` away. So...

```
char *p = malloc(SOME_NUMBER * sizeof char);
p++;     // p = p + sizeof char
p += 4;  // p = p + sizeof char * 4
```

And if you have a struct...

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
} foo;

/* ... */

foo *fp = malloc(SOME_NUMBER * sizeof foo);
fp++;    // fp = fp + sizeof foo;
fp += 4; // fp = fp + sizeof foo * 4;
```

Comment: Note that `p` starts as a null pointer, and performing arithmetic on it has undefined behavior.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Yeah I thought of that, but I decided it wasn't  relevant.  Since this is a beginner... it may be a good idea to change it.

Comment: Note that `* sizeof char` is redundant, since `sizeof char` is 1 by definition.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I know that `sizeof char` is guaranteed to be 1, but for the purpose of illustration I think it is better to include it.

Comment: Your comments are a bit misleading. Technically speaking, `p + (4 * sizeof char)` increases pointer value to `(4 * sizeof char) * (sizeof char)`. Just some english words perhaps? Or maybe casting to some unsigned integer type?

Comment: @Nya: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: @EdS.: Fair enough. But your example `fp += 4; // fp = fp + sizeof foo * 4;` could be confusing. You're using two different meanings of `+` the one in `fp += 4;` is C-style pointer arithmetic (which is implicitly scaled by the size of the pointed-to type), and the `+` in the comment is in bytes.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Yeah, I was trying to show the difference between pointer arithmetic and what is actually happening (in terms of the pointer's value) behind the scenes.  Perhaps I didn't chose the best way to do that.